# Mule File endpoint download incomplete file without EOF

Tags: file, mule, endpoint

Mule flow must download big and huge XML files to process. When provider writes a file in input folder, in the same time File endpoint component can download incomplete file or provider cannot complete write process for some reasons. Does Mule API provide handling the situation?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file connector doesn't download data, are you mixing up with the HTTP connector? Or do you mean the Mule file transport picks-up a file while it is still being copied by the file producer?

If the latter, the best option is to write to file into a temporary location then move it to the Mule pick-up folder because moving a file is an atomic operation.

Alternatively, you can use the `fileAge` attribute on the file connector to configure Mule to only pick-up files that are older than the specified age. This can work only if you have an idea of the maximum time it takes the file writer to write the file.

Comment: David, Thank you for fileAge hint. In my question I did not use word "connector", I mean Mule file transport which try to pick up file while it is still being copied by the file producer. I have proprietary decision. but I would like to know about standard means  of Mule API like fileAge.

Comment: Read the manual: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference#FileTransportReference-ExtendingthisModuleorTransportBestPractices