# Processing a file after its data is being completely written in mule esb

Tags: xml, file, mule

I have a flow(X) that has **File outbound endpoint**, that writes an **XML file** (let us say 'A')to some directory .It is of some large size 80 MB  . I have a flow(Y) that reads this file and processes it and writes the data to 6 different files.

The problem is Flow(Y) reads this file before file('A') data is completely written by Flow(X).

What configuration do I need to do in my file connector to acheive this.

Please help me in this regard.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found a question that is very relavant to my requirement. Please a have look at the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267476/mule-file-endpoint-download-incomplete-file-without-eof?rq=1.

But the issue in the above URL question is, how would i move the file from the temporary location to my pickUp folder automatically. Some one pls help. I am bit new to Mule esb.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the second flow?
Are you using file inbound for the second flow? This could be the problem.

You could use this alternatives:

- VM : After the flow (A) creates the file (80mb), call a vm outbound with one-way(async) or request-response(sync) depending on the behavior you need:

[image]

```
<flow name="flow_A">
    ...several steps...
    <file:outbound-endpoint doc:name="create 80mb file"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="vm.process.file" doc:name="process file"/>
</flow>

<flow name="flow_B">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="vm.process.file" doc:name="proces file"/>
     ...read 80mb and split...
</flow>
```

- Flow Reference: After the flow (A) creates the file (80mb), use a "flow referece" point to flow(B). In flow(B) set process strategy to : sync or async depending on the behavior you need:

[image]

```
<flow name="flow_A">
    ...several steps...
    <file:outbound-endpoint doc:name="create 80mb file"/>
    <flow-ref name="flow_B" doc:name="flow_B"/>
</flow>
<flow name="flow_B" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    ... read 80mb and split ...
</flow>
```

Regards

Comment: Yess i am using file inbound for the second flow. I need to use file inbound in the second flow. So is there an alternative with that configuration??

Comment: Yes. For the second flow you could use a vm or flow reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying **fileAge** in your file-connector for Flow(Y)?

`<file:connector name="input" fileAge="500" autoDelete="true" pollingFrequency="100" moveToDirectory="/backup" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']].backup"/>`

The fileAge is defined milliseconds and tells Mule to wait for a certain period before locking the file for processing.